# OpenCV: set image borders, without padding

Tags: c++, opencv

how can I set an image's border of a given size to black, WITHOUT padding, i.e., I just want to set the image borders to black (zero), and the output will be an image with the same size as source.

Comment: I would start by attempting to do it before asking on SO.

Comment: Before judging @ScarletAmaranth you should have shared what you tried so far.

Answer (score 9):

You can simply draw a black rectangle on your image:

```
cv::Mat image;
cv::Rect border(cv::Point(0, 0), image.size());
cv::Scalar color(0, 0, 0);
int thickness = 1;

cv::rectangle(image, border, color, thickness);
```

Comment: If the border color is white or black, should it change the file image size, in Kb? I'm afraid that this could change my image quality because the size is quite smaller.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [copyMakeBorder](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#copymakeborder) with the BORDER_ISOLATED flag.

```
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("lena.png");
cv::Mat output;

const int border = 10;
const int borderType = cv::BORDER_CONSTANT | cv::BORDER_ISOLATED;
const cv::Scalar value(0, 0, 0);
const cv::Rect roi(border, border, image.cols-2*border, image.rows-2*border);
cv::copyMakeBorder(image(roi), output, border, border, border, border, borderType, value);

cv::imshow("input", image);
cv::imshow("output", output);
cv::waitKey(0);
```